# C# MD5 and or other encryption oledb (access 2007)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, encryption, ms-access-2007

Done a little bit of research on encryption and some of the pros and cons. I have a pretty valid login system which uses command parameters to pass the user info to the sql string to try and avoid sql injection. my next goal however, is to encrypt the password upon creation and then store it hashed in the database.

I'm programming in C#, using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 and Access 2007.

I'm not looking for a straight up answer although i wouldnt complain if someone gave me one, but if someone could atleast point me in the right direction that would be great thanks! :D

Kind Regads, Nick

Comment: Use a slow (iterated) hash and a salt. Single iteration hashes are bad, even if it's SHA-2. See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords). In C# the easiest solution is to use [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) with at least 10000 iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using a secure hash algorithm (SHA) with a salt.

The purpose of a hash algorithm in this context is to store a token representing the users password. You will not actually store the password and ideally from the hash you should not be able to recreate the users password in plaintext.

When a login attempt is made you will pass the supplied password through the same process and see if the hash values match.

Comment: Thaks for the response, is there any difference between sha-1 and sha-256? Im going to assume the 256 is the number of bits converted to??

Comment: There are lots of SHA versions available. SHA-1 was a 160-bit standard and had some weaknesses. SHA-256 is part of the SHA-2 standard. There is a nice overview on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm. It is important to keep in mind that security is really difficult to get right, if you are not comfortable with it and if you are trying to protect important data you really need to spend sometime doing a bit fo research. There is a great podcast called securitynow on the twit network that has some really nice discussions. Oh and yes 256 will reflect the size of the hash value.

Comment: Choice of hash algorithm is almost irrelevant here. There are no practical attacks on even MD5 in this context. There is also little reason to use an output size >128 bit, regardless of the choice of hash. But it is essential to use a slow/iterated scheme and you didn't mention that.